# Ajax частичное обновление страницы не срабатывает событие клик по кнопке

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

Есть страница. На ней- форма. Она загружается по-умолчанию при загрузке страницы. Рядом с формой есть ссылки на замену данных в форме.
При клике на ссылку старая форма удаляется и загружается форма с другим содержимым.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/chat/load-dialog?id='+dialogId,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
            $('.direct-chat ').remove();
            $('.dialog_box').html(data);
            },
                 });
```

Проблема в том, что в форме по-умолчанию событие click срабатывает, а в форме загруженной через ajax- событие клик не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема не в загруженной форме, а в том что как вызывается этот метод click. Я предположу что проблема в том что у вас написано так:

```
$("YOUR_SELECTOR").click(function() {
  //что-то там
});
```

и этот код не знает о новой загруженной форме. Так что подправьте на вот такой вызов:

```
$(document).on("click", "YOUR_SELECTOR", function() {
  //что-то там
});
```

во втором случае динамически созданные элементы тоже будут обработаны

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам  понял это.
Глупый вопрос задал.

Comment: @VitautHryharovich всё в порядке, нет глупых вопросов глупо не задавать вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто. Там, где идёт вызов метода ajax.success добавляем событие клик по кнопке.
Я добавлял так
$('.form').on('submit', function(e) { });